# Force a paper cut at the end of each page in StimulSoft

Tags: c#, .net, stimulsoft

I am using pos printer and I want to Force a paper cut at the end of each page by StimulSoft

Comment: Let us know how you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is about printer settings
go to the printer preferences and in the page/job label select Partial Cut / Partial Cut